# If a > b for every value of a (a is a vector and b is a scalar)

Tags: matlab

I want to execute something if **all** values in `line(1:5)` are greater than `50`. How would I do that?

> >> line(1:5)
>
> ```
>  ans =
>
>   93    96    96    99   101
> ```
>
> >> line(1:5) > 50
>
> ```
>  ans =
>
>    1     1     1     1     1
> ```
>
> >> line(1:5) > 100
>
> ```
>  ans =
>
>    0     0     0     0     1
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if *all* elements satisfy a condition use this ([`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html)):

```
all_elem_gt_50 = all( line(1:5) > 50 );
```

In expressions where logical value is expected (e.g. in `while` loop, or in `if` statement) you can use `line(1:5) > 50` and it would behave same as `all( line(1:5) > 50 )`. For example, these two `if` statements are equal:

```
if( line(1:5) > 50 )
    % do something
end

if ( all( line(1:5) > 50 ) )
    % do something
end
```

Comment: A related function is [any](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html): `true` if *at least 1* element is `true`, false otherwise.